# Powershell executes old code version after modifications

Tags: powershell, caching

I know this topic is ooold, but unanswered in all communities I found. It is very indiviual.

I have a script, using classes from an external class file.

The classes are named `x.psm1"` and imported via `Using module ".\x.psm1"`

Here is some Code (censored)

**Logger.psm1**

```
class Logger 
{
    [string] $LogFile = ""
    ...

    Logger()
    {
        ...
    }

    Logger([string] $logFile)
    {
        if($logFile.Length -gt 0){
            $this.LogFile = $logFile
        }

        ...
    }

    ...

    # Logging works fine now, so I will not list all methods.
}
```

**TestRunner.psm1**

```
# Usings
Using module ".\Logger.psm1"

class TestRunner
{ 
    [Logger] $Logger
    [string] $RootPath = ""
    [string] $LogPath = ""
    [string] $RegExFilter = ""

    TestRunner([Logger] $logger)
    {
        $this.Logger = $logger
    }

    Execute()
    {
       $this.Logger.WriteInformation("Test", $false) 
       # After changing "Test" to "Other" it will still output "Test"
    }
}
```

**StartTestRunner.ps1**

```
# Usings
Using module ".\Logger.psm1"
Using module ".\TestRunner.psm1"

# Parameters
param(
    [switch] $Help,
    [switch] $P1, # ParameterSet "P1"
    [switch] $P2, # ParameterSet "P2"
    [string] $RootPath,
    [string] $LogPath,
    [string] $RegEx
)

# Fields
$LogFile = "$(Get-Location)\TestLog.txt"
if($LogPath.Length -gt 0)
{
    $LogFile = $LogPath
}

[Logger] $Logger = [Logger]::new($LogFile)#

function ValidateParamsAndRun
{
    ValidateParameterSets

    if($Help)   {ShowHelp}
    
    if($RootPath.Length -eq 0){
        $RootPath = Get-Location
        $Logger.LogWarning("No path provided. Using default: $($RootPath)")
    }

    if($P1)    
    {
        $Logger.LogInformation("Starting P1 tests")
        [TestRunner]$runner = [TestRunner]::new($Logger)
        $runner.RootPath = $RootPath
        $runner.RegExFilter = $RegEx

        $runner.Execute()
    }
    if($P2)
    {
        ...
    }

function ValidateParameterSets
{
    $count = 0
    if($Help) {$count++}
    if($P1) {$count++}
    if($P2) {$count++}

    if($count -gt 1)
    {
        $Logger.LogError("Invalid parameters found. Please use '-Help' to see options.
        ")
        Exit(-1)
    }
}

function ShowHelp
{
    WriteInformation "
    Give some 
    multiline Help.
    It works.
    "
}

# Main Program starts here
ValidateParamsAndRun
```

I tried the MS-PS-ISE and VS Code with PowerShell Extension.

I executed the script with the internal terminals of each and with an external PS-Window.

I tried this solution [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502611/does-powershell-have-a-cache-that-needs-to-be-cleared), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023648/windows-powershell-ise-running-old-version) and did not know what to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006107/powershell-ise-loading-old-version-of-script).

The only thing that worksis to close and restart the Terminal. But this is not my expectation for writing code :-)

Coming from C#, my thought was, if there are errors in the code, it dosn't compile and executes the old version instead, but without a warning. Does PowerShell behave like that? Another problem is, that most error messages don't show the file or the line of code they occur.

Are there any cache options?

Comment: When an error occurs not all object are disposed.  I found files are left open after a PS script fails and then I cannot run the script again because I do not have permission to write to files that were left open. See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?force_isolation=true

Comment: The short of it: you cannot force-reload a module that was loaded via a `using module` statement - yet you need the latter in order to import _classes_. If classes weren't in the picture, you could use `Import-Module -Force`
Otherwise, you either need a workaround that requires modifying the source code _or_, if you're using Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension, configure it to start a new, temporary session for every debugging run. See the linked duplicate for details.